# Using Joose with Meteor

Tags: meteor, joose

What is the best way to use Joose with Meteor (or Meteorite)?

I have only managed to get Joose working if I load the joose-all.min.js but this doesn't seem to allow me to use other Joose libraries (inparticular JoosX-Attribute).

I have also tried creating a package that has in it's package.js file

```
Npm.depends({
    'joose' : '3.50.0'
});
```

but that just causes meteor to fail to start with the following error

```
/home/dev/GDL/gdl-csr/meteor/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:337 
}).run();
     ^ ReferenceError: Joose is not defined
    at app/gdl-csr.js:1:16
    at /home/dev/GDL/gdl-csr/meteor/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:298:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/dev/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
    at run (/home/dev/GDL/gdl-csr/meteor/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:239:7)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any suggestions to get me going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In meteor variables are scoped to their particular file. So you need to expose `Joose`. You would have to in one of your lib files use

```
Joose = Npm.require('joose');
```

as opposed to

```
var Joose = Npm.require('joose');
```

Comment: Any idea why not using var is required? I though all variables (in modern javascript) should be declared.

Comment: You could use `var` but then the variable would be scoped locally to that file, i.e you can't access it outside the file. Without it its still a variable declaration but it can be accessed in any file